# Seeking advice for showing videocard/youtube video in Telegram using Microsoft BotFramework

Tags: node.js, botframework, telegram-bot

My goal is to show a youtube video (preferably in card form) in telegram, while keeping my code as 'channel-agnostic' as possible by using the botbuilder module.

Can anyone tell me why Telegram shows the videocard as a plain image using this NodeJS example taken from the official sample [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards) (createVideoCard() example)? (same behaviour for youtube links).

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

function (session, results, next) {
    const msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .addAttachment(new builder.VideoCard(session)
            .title('Big Buck Bunny')
            .subtitle('by the Blender Institute')
            .text('Big Buck Bunny (code-named Peach) is a short computer-animated comedy film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation. Like the foundation\'s previous film Elephants Dream, the film was made using Blender, a free software application for animation made by the same foundation. It was released as an open-source film under Creative Commons License Attribution 3.0.')
            .image(builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg'))
            .media([{ url: 'http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4' }])
            .buttons([builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://peach.blender.org/', 'Learn More')]);

    session.send(msg);
}
```

While, using:

```
session.send('youtube link');
```

is recognised by Telegram and rendered as youtube video.

I have read the following on [richcard support](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards):

> The Animation card, Video card and Audio card used in this sample are
>   fully supported in the following channels:
>
> Skype Facebook WebChat
>
> They are also supported, with some limitations,
>   in the following channel:
>
> Slack (Only Animation card is supported) 
>   GroupMe Telegram (Only
>   Animation and Audio cards are supported) Email

How can I best achieve my goal?

Comment: I think you said everything... you want to use a card but `Telegram (Only Animation and Audio cards are supported)` so currently there is no way to do this.
Telegram is automatically handling youtube links when you send them, it's not on the bot side, that's why you got it